# what does this jQuery code means?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw the following code in an anonymous javascript function and can't understand how it is useful?

```
(function($, undefined)
{
    var src = $('script:last').attr('src'); // <- how is this line of code useful
    // more code to follow.....

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: *"how is this line of code useful"* I assume the code does something with the value of the `src` attribute (in `// more code to follow.....`). So, the line is useful because the value is needed.

Comment: It's getting the URL of the last `<script>` tag in the document. It's probably called by code actually *loaded* by that tag, so that it can check the URL for flags, parameters, or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It obtains the `src` attribute of the last script tag in the document.

How exactly that is useful depends entirely upon what you're trying to do.

Occasionally I've seen javascript that wants to get some server-provided argument off the end of a script URL or even a domain out of that URL and this will allow you to do that.

If the code is being run from a script that was itself loaded via a `<script>` tag, then it serves to get the URL that the current script was loaded from.  This works because the parser executes the script in a script tag before it inserts any more of the page into the DOM.  So at the point the script from a `<script>` tag is being run, the last `<script>` tag in the document is the currently executing script (assuming no `async` or `defer` attributes are present on the script tag).

---

I should add that there is no `.src` attribute for inline scripts so this only obtains something useful for an external script that uses the `.src` attribute on the `<script>` tag.

Comment: thanks for clearing up my confusion on how this code may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

That code is simply retrieving the url source of the last script element of the page.